# Determine the source of read-only docker violation

Tags: linux, bash, docker, readonly

I have a container with a complex, multi-threaded software.

I am now in a process of trying to make it run in read-only mode (with rw mounted `/tmp` directory).

The problem is that the software fails to start as it attempts to modify several files.

Is there a way to determine which files are being modified?

For example:

```sh
docker run --name alpine --read-only --rm --tty alpine
docker exec alpine touch hello.txt // access violation
```

I want to know that something inside the container tried to modify hello.txt.

Comment: How quickly does it die? If you can attach strace to the process after the container is created you can track write attempts `strace -Tfe trace=open,read,write -p <pid>`

Comment: An easier solution might be to just run the container in rw mode and then use `docker diff` to determine what files were modified.

Comment: Build a custom image that runs your "complex, multi-threaded" software under the control of `strace`, and looks for calls to the `open` system call.